# The required property 'blobName' is missing from the request

Tags: blob, azure-blob-storage, azure-stream-analytics, http-status-code-422

I am trying to create one stream analytics job in azure with one input of type stream and another of type Reference programatically (both by C# Code and Powershell). I am able to create the job with stream input, however when i go and create Reference type input (Azure Blob) I get the error

New-AzureRmStreamAnalyticsJob : HTTP Status Code: 422
Error Code: 422
Error Message: The required property 'blobName' is missing from the request.
Request Id: b1bd2f67-8b69-4948-8800-184e171f6040
Timestamp (Utc):03/07/2018 08:52:11
At line:21 char:1
+ New-AzureRmStreamAnalyticsJob -File "C:\Users\rakesh.khanna\Desktop\A ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmStreamAnalyticsJob], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.StreamAnalytics.NewAzureStreamAnalyticsJobCommand.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably need to show some code. From the error message I'd say you're not specifying the name of the blob container you're trying to retrieve data from.

Comment: Hi, in order to investigate this we will need to see the code you used to create this input.